# problem with deleting from list in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to programmatically create views (seats of student) based on data that i get from room. I have the screen in which i create draggable views:

```
@Composable
fun SeatsScreen(
    navController: NavController
) {
val context = LocalContext.current

val viewModel: SeatsViewModel = hiltViewModel()

val seatsWithStudentsList = viewModel.seatsWithStudentsList.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

val selectedSeatWithStudent = viewModel.selectedSeatWithStudent.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

val studentList = viewModel.studentsList

val showAddSeatsDialog by viewModel.showAddSeatsDialog.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

val showDeleteSeatDialog by viewModel.showDeleteSeatsDialog.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(title = {
            Text(
                text = "Seats",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Start
            )
        },
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        navController.popBackStack()
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Rounded.ArrowBack,
                        contentDescription = ""
                    )
                }
            },
            actions = {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        //viewModel.start()
                        if (studentList.isNotEmpty()) {
                            viewModel.showAddSeatDialog(true)
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                context,
                                "No students!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                }
            })
    }
) { innerPadding ->
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(innerPadding)
    ) {
        seatsWithStudentsList.value?.forEach { seatWithStudent ->
            MultipleDraggableObject(
                seatWithStudent = seatWithStudent,
                onEvent = viewModel::onEvent
            )
        }

        if (showDeleteSeatDialog) {
            selectedSeatWithStudent.value?.seat?.let {
                DialogConfirmSeatDelete(
                    seat = it,
                    title = "Delete place!",
                    message = "Continue?",
                    onEvent = viewModel::onEvent
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MultipleDraggableObject(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    seatWithStudent: SeatWithStudent,
    onEvent: (SeatsEvent) -> Unit
) {
    val offsetX = remember { mutableStateOf(seatWithStudent.seat.x) }
    val offsetY = remember { mutableStateOf(seatWithStudent.seat.y) }
    val zIndex = remember {
        mutableStateOf(1f)
    }

    Card(
        modifier = modifier
            .height(60.dp)
            .width(50.dp)
            .padding(
                start = 2.dp,
                end = 2.dp
            )
            .zIndex(zIndex.value)
            .offset {
                IntOffset(
                    x = offsetX.value.roundToInt(),
                    y = offsetY.value.roundToInt(),
                )
            }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(
                    onLongPress = {
                        onEvent(seatWithStudent.let { it1 ->
                            SeatsEvent.OnLongPress(
                                x = offsetX.value.roundToInt(),
                                y = offsetY.value.roundToInt(),
                                seatWithStudent = it1
                            )
                        }
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures(
                    onDragStart = {
                        zIndex.value = zIndex.value + 100
                        onEvent(
                            SeatsEvent.OnDragStart(
                                seatWithStudent
                            )
                        )
                    },
                    onDragEnd = {
                        zIndex.value = zIndex.value - 100
                        onEvent(
                            SeatsEvent.OnDragEnd(
                                x = offsetX.value.roundToInt(),
                                y = offsetY.value.roundToInt()
                            )
                        )
                    }
                ) { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consume()
                    offsetX.value += dragAmount.x
                    offsetY.value += dragAmount.y
                }
            },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        border = BorderStroke(
            1.dp,
            MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
        )
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(4.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {

            val painter =
                if (seatWithStudent.student.photoPath == "" || seatWithStudent.student.photoPath == null) {
                    when (seatWithStudent.student.gender) {
                        Gender.Boy.gender -> painterResource(id = R.drawable.boy)
                        Gender.Girl.gender -> painterResource(id = R.drawable.girl)
                        else -> painterResource(id = R.drawable.nophoto)
                    }
                } else {
                    // TODO Να βάλω το path της κανονικής φωτογραφίας
                    painterResource(id = R.drawable.nophoto)
                }

            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(28.dp)
                    .wrapContentHeight(),
                painter = painter,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Inside,
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground),
                contentDescription = "studentItemPhoto"
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                text = seatWithStudent.student.lastName ?: "",
                fontSize = 6.sp,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 1,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                text = seatWithStudent.student.firstName ?: "",
                fontSize = 6.sp,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 1,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
    }
}
```

and the viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class SeatsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val seatRepository: SeatRepository,
    private val sectionStudentRepository: SectionStudentRepository,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    val idSection = savedStateHandle.get<Int>(ID_SECTION)

    private val _lessons = MutableStateFlow<RequestState<List<YearWithLessons>>>(RequestState.Idle)
    val lessons: StateFlow<RequestState<List<YearWithLessons>>> = _lessons

    private val _seatsWithStudentsList = MutableStateFlow<List<SeatWithStudent>?>(null)
    val seatsWithStudentsList: StateFlow<List<SeatWithStudent>?> = _seatsWithStudentsList

    private val _selectedSeatWithStudent = MutableStateFlow<SeatWithStudent?>(null)
    val selectedSeatWithStudent: StateFlow<SeatWithStudent?> = _selectedSeatWithStudent

    private val _studentsList = mutableStateListOf<Student>()
    val studentsList: List<Student> = _studentsList

    private val _seatsList = mutableStateListOf<SeatWithStudent>()
    val seatsList: List<SeatWithStudent> = _seatsList

    private val _seat = MutableStateFlow<Seat?>(null)
    val seat: StateFlow<Seat?> = _seat

    private val _student = MutableStateFlow<Student?>(null)
    val student: StateFlow<Student?> = _student

    private val _showAddSeatsDialog = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val showAddSeatsDialog: StateFlow<Boolean> = _showAddSeatsDialog

    private val _showDeleteSeatsDialog = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val showDeleteSeatsDialog: StateFlow<Boolean> = _showDeleteSeatsDialog

    private val _selectedSeatId = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val selectedSeatId: StateFlow<Int> = _selectedSeatId

    private val _itemIdsList = MutableStateFlow(listOf<Int>())
    val itemIdsList: StateFlow<List<Int>> get() = _itemIdsList

    init {
        start()
    }

    fun start() {
        itemIdsList.value.toMutableList().clear()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (idSection != null) {
                seatRepository.getSeatsWithStudent(idSection = idSection).collectLatest { list ->
                    _seatsWithStudentsList.value = list
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun showAddSeatDialog(value: Boolean) {
        _showAddSeatsDialog.value = value
    }

    private fun showDeleteSeatDialog(value: Boolean) {
        _showDeleteSeatsDialog.value = value
    }

    fun onEvent(event: DialogConfirmSeatDeleteEvent) {
        when (event) {
            DialogConfirmSeatDeleteEvent.OnCancel -> {
                showDeleteSeatDialog(false)
            }
            is DialogConfirmSeatDeleteEvent.OnOk -> {
                showDeleteSeatDialog(false)
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    try {
                        seatRepository.deleteSeat(event.seat)
                    }
                    finally {
                        //TODO
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun onEvent(event: SeatsEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is SeatsEvent.OnDragStart -> {
                _selectedSeatWithStudent.value = event.seatWithStudent
            }
            is SeatsEvent.OnDragEnd -> {
                _seat.value = _selectedSeatWithStudent.value?.seat?.copy(
                    x = event.x.toFloat(),
                    y = event.y.toFloat()
                )
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    seat.value.let {
                        if (it != null) {
                            seatRepository.insertUpdateSeat(
                                it
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            is SeatsEvent.OnDrag -> TODO()
            is SeatsEvent.OnLongPress -> {
                _selectedSeatWithStudent.value = event.seatWithStudent
                _seat.value = _selectedSeatWithStudent.value?.seat?.copy(
                    x = event.x.toFloat(),
                    y = event.y.toFloat()
                )
                _student.value = event.seatWithStudent.student
                _selectedSeatId.value = event.seatWithStudent.seat.idSeat!!
                showDeleteSeatDialog(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected until trying to delete a seat. When i delete a seat it not deletes the table i select but other one. Can someone help me?